# acl library for node.js

Tags: node.js, acl

Is there any library to do [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) in node.js?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It looks like there isn't according to [npm registry](http://search.npmjs.org/) and [modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules) page.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/superafroman/connect-security, but not updated in a while

Comment: This answer is pretty outdated. Could you update it (even though it's old, this question is still ranked first in Google search)?. The npm registry now contains a sh*t load of ACL modules!! https://npmjs.org/search?q=acl

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for some simple ACL module as well but there really weren't many that's simple enough. None of the modules touting "simple" or "minimimal" really were. Some are just ports.

So I wrote one:

```
npm install simple-acl
```

This module is so simple it only has 3 important APIs:

- `acl.grant('someone', 'something', callback);`
- `acl.revoke('someone', 'fromSomething', callback);`
- `acl.assert('someone', 'canAccessSomething', function(e, ok) { })` - `ok === true` if you have `grant()`-ed something earlier and `ok === false` otherwise.

For other APIs, check the readme on GitHub:
https://github.com/chakrit/simple-acl

Pardon the shameless plug :)
Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I can't vouch for any of these in particular, but two that I've tagged are:

https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl

https://github.com/cellkast/node-acl

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

https://github.com/scottkf/ability-js

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at node_acl:

https://npmjs.org/package/acl

https://github.com/optimalbits/node_acl

Supports express middleware and Redis/Mongo/in-memory based backends, as well as a generic interface.